# Classification of monohedral plane tilings with non-convex hexagons

Tags: geometry, tiling

Is a classification of monohedral plane tilings with non-convex hexagons known or unknown? I prepare a seminar for talented basic school pupils and I would like to talk about monohedral tiling problem. Before that, I want to be sure what is known and what is not known. With triangles and quads it is clear, with convex pentagons it seems to be clear due to the proof from 2017, with convex hexagons it is also clear, with non-convex pentagons it is surely unclear due to the unsolved Einstein problem. With non-convex hexagons I was unable to find out if it is open or not, therefore I ask here. (If there is something known about non-convex pentagon tiling, I am also interested.).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the non-convex pentagon and hexagon tiles are open problems. Note that there is a big difference between classifying the polygons that tile, and classifying all the monohedral tiling patterns because a tile with a known tiling pattern may well allow other nice tiling patterns, especially if you have some degrees of freedom in the original tile/tiling. I have lots of tiling patterns with non-convex tiles on [my website here](https://www.jaapsch.net/tilings/nonconvex.htm).

Comment: Thank you Jaap, this helps! It is not a subject I work on, therefore I was not sure.